# Edit attribute in script string with AST

Tags: python, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm unfamiliar with the AST module and would appreciate any insight. If, for example, I have a *string* that contains a valid python script such as

```
import sys #Just any module
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.b = 15
    def a_func(self):
        print(self.x)
```

I would like to be able to programmatically edit lines such as changing `self.x = 10` to something like `self.x = 20`. I can break it down somewhat with `ast` via:

```
some_string = "..." #String of class above
for body_item in ast.parse(some_string):
    ...
```

But this doesn't feel like the "right" way(not that there is a right way since this is somewhat niche). I was hoping someone could correct me towards something cleaner, or just better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by using `ast.dump` to get an idea of the AST structure of the code you're dealing with:

```
import ast

code='self.x = 10'
print(ast.dump(ast.parse(code), indent=2))
```

This outputs:

```
Module(
  body=[
    Assign(
      targets=[
        Attribute(
          value=Name(id='self', ctx=Load()),
          attr='x',
          ctx=Store())],
      value=Constant(value=10))],
  type_ignores=[])
```

From which you can see what you want to look for is an `Assign` node where the first of `targets` is an `Attribute` node whose `value` is a `Name` node with an `id` of `'self'` and an `attr` of `'x'`.

With this knowledge, you can then use `ast.walk` to traverse the AST nodes to look for a node with the aforementioned properties, modify its `value` to a `Constant` node with a `value` of `20`, and finally use `ast.unparse` to convert AST back to a string of code:

```
import ast

code = '''
import sys #Just any module
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.b = 15
    def a_func(self):
        print(self.x)
'''
tree = ast.parse(code)
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if (
        isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and
        isinstance((target := node.targets[0]), ast.Attribute) and
        isinstance(target.value, ast.Name) and
        target.value.id == 'self' and
        target.attr == 'x'
    ):
        node.value = ast.Constant(value=20)
print(ast.unparse(tree))
```

This outputs:

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20
        self.b = 15

    def a_func(self):
        print(self.x)
```

Note that `ast.unparse` requires Python 3.10 or later. If you're using an earlier version, you can use `astunparse.unparse` from the [astunparse package](https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse) instead.

Demo: https://trinket.io/python3/3b09901326